# In python, how can I get scrapy to return the contents of an element that is hidden?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy in Python and would like to retrieve the contents of an element that is behind another "expand" element.  In examining the DOM tree, the div tags and text itself are not loaded until the parent element is first clicked. Once the parent is clicked, the text can be re-hidden, but will at least be in the DOM.

An example website is [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleListURL&_method=list&_ArticleListID=-764831607&_sort=r&_st=13&view=c&md5=a41e9f25739feae932862575251c1e0d&searchtype=a). Where I am looking for the Abstract text (which is not loaded until the "Abstract" link is clicked).

The scrappy command is:
 `response.xpath("//div[@class='previewBox abstract hidden']").extract()` but that returns a bunch of empty divs like this:
  `u'<div id="abs_S0740002015000179" class="previewBox abstract hidden"></div>'`

If I use this: `response.xpath("//div[@class='previewBox abstract']").extract()` then it doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *simulate that additional HTTP GET request* being sent on `abtract` link click.

The idea is to extract and make a request to the `data-url` attribute value of the "Abstract" link.

Demo from the ["Scrapy Shell"](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleListURL&_method=list&_ArticleListID=-764831607&_sort=r&_st=13&view=c&md5=a41e9f25739feae932862575251c1e0d&searchtype=a"
In [1]: url = response.xpath("//a[@data-type='abstract']/@data-url").extract()[0]
In [2]: fetch(url)
In [3]: print "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='articleText']//text()").extract())
AbstractThe aim of the present study was to investigate the effect of lactic acid against Shiga toxin producing Escherichia coli (O157:H7 and non-O157 serogroups including O103, O111, O145 and O26) at different conditions. Soybean sprouts and spinach leaves inoculated with each serogroup of E. coli (∼7.00 + 1.00 log10 cfu/g) were treated with the lactic acid solutions at different concentrations (0% (control), 1.5%, 2.0%, or 2.5%) and at different temperatures (20, 40, or 50 °C) for 3 min. Results indicated that regardless of the treatment temperature, no significant reduction in the numbers of any serogroup occurred in the control group (0%) (p > 0.05). However, lactic acid at concentration of 1.5%, 2% and 2.5% was found to be effective against all organisms tested. There was no significant difference (p > 0.05) between E. coli O157:H7 and non-O157 STEC serogroups at any treatment group. The highest reductions (ca. 4.00 log10 cfu/g) of all serotypes in both produces were observed after immersing into 2.5% lactic acid at 50 °C. The results of this study showed that decontamination of fresh produces such as spinach and soybean sprout with lactic acid solutions prepared at mild temperatures (40 °C and 50 °C) might be an effective safety measure in preventing public health risks associated with these products contaminated with STEC.
```

Note that this `fetch()` call is a special way to make additional requests in the shell. In your Scrapy spider, you would need to `yield` or `return` the [`scrapy.http.Request()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) instance and parse the result in the `callback`.

Comment: I see what you are doing, and that makes sense...  but it appears Id have to loop through the fetch command, would I need to do that in the spider as well?  If I put in a loop here (so url is a list of urls), the print command is only returning the last abstract on the page... am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @claudiaann1 in the spider you would need to loop over the links, yield requests to data-urls and grab the contents of the response in the callback. Let me know if you need an example code. Meanwhile, I think we can resolve the topic. Thanks.